# Where did Mapsforge mapgenerator go?

Tags: android, mapsforge, openseamap

In MapsForge there was a MapGenerator class (At least in version 0.3) that was being used in an GitHub application: android-ais-openseamap-plotter which I use for reference.

I am now using the new MapsForge 0.52 and am unable to find the replacement.

My goal is to make available online OpenSeaMap maps in my application.